# Cannot install dotnet sdk on mac

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, apple-m1, macos-big-sur

I have installed dotnet sdk from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/download

after installing I run on terminal: `dotnet --version`
and I get : `zsh: command not found: dotnet`

I have operating system: macOS Big Sur 11.6 on MacBook Air (M1, 2020)

Comment: Have you tried changing your working directory to the install location and running the command from there?

Comment: @Jasen yes i have tried that:
I run ls and the dotnet is there but still it does not work:

`Last login: Thu Dec  9 09:42:07 on ttys001
drilonahm@Drilons-MacBook-Air x64 % ls
LICENSE.txt  host   sdk-manifests
ThirdPartyNotices.txt packs   shared
dotnet   sdk   templates
drilonahm@Drilons-MacBook-Air x64 % dotnet --version
zsh: command not found: dotnet
drilonahm@Drilons-MacBook-Air x64 % `

Comment: So it's installed (the files exist). But did you modify your PATH? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/macos#download-and-manually-install

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by downloading and installing `Visual Studio 2022` for Mac:

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/preview/

It will download the dotnet SDK also